# Retrieving date difference php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I would like to count the date difference which the user select from the datepicker through `$_POST`. Both `$from` and `$to` returns date picked by the user from the form but the `date_diff` and other user's method wouldn't work, thus posting this. I am only interested in the date, so time is not important for me.

This is my code:

```
$from = $_POST['dateFrom'];
$to = $_POST['dateTo'];

echo $from; 
echo $to; 

$newFrom = strtotime($from);
$newFormatFrom = date('m-d-Y',$newFrom);

$newTo = strtotime($to);
$newFormatTo = date('m-d-Y',$newTo);    

$dateDiff = date_diff($newFormatFrom, $newFormatTo);
```

Comment: `date_diff()` is an alias for the `DateTime::diff` method. Have a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) for examples of how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$noofdays = (strtotime($to)-strtotime($from))/(60*60*24);
print $noofdays;
```

Comment: Thank you @MayurKoshti. Your solution helps in my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

 $from = strtotime($_POST['dateFrom']);
 $to = strtotime($_POST['dateTo']);
 $datediff = $to - $from;
 echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24));

?>
```

Comment: N Raju You can't directly minus in this way as it returns 0 irregardless of any date gap selected by user. However, the floor is something that I've not seen, all along I have been using is `echo $abc`. Thanks for the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

use  date_create function, may be this will help you:

```
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12");

$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
```